# ¿Cómo puedo restar dos fechas en c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

¿Cómo puedo restar dos fechas en `C#`?

Tengo dos variables `DateTime` y necesito conseguir la diferencia entre ambas en horas.

```
DateTime fecharegistro = {04/05/2018 8:34:01} //obtenemos este valor de una base de datos
DateTime fechafin = DateTime.Now.Substract(fechaRegistro);
```

Al compilar el código anterior me lanza un error que dice que no se puede convertir implícitamente un obejto `TimeStamp` en `System.DateTime`, cuando la variable es `DateTime`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

La resta de 2 fechas nunca te va a dar un `DateTime`, sino un [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx). Si quieres saber el numero de horas, simplemente accede a la propiedad [`TotalHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx) de la resta:

```
DateTime fecharegistro = DateTime.Parse("04/05/2018 8:34:01"); //obtenemos este valor de una bbdd
var horas = (DateTime.Now-fecharegistro).TotalHours;
```

P.D. no es necesario usar el método `Substract` de `DateTime`.Puedes simplemente restar las fechas (`fecha2-fecha1`).

Si quieres formatear el resultado de una forma legible, puedes usar un formato, como por ejemplo:

```
var horas = (DateTime.Now - fecharegistro).ToString(@"dd\d\ hh\h\ mm\m\ ");
```

Este código devuelve una cadena del tipo `04d 01h 44m`

Comment: Gracias por lo de la cadena :)

Answer (score 16):

La suma o la resta de fechas te retorna un [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx). Por lo tanto podes obtener las horas directamente del resultado de esa resta.

```
var fecharegistro = DateTime.Parse("04/05/2018 8:34:01");
var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - fecharegistro;

Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.TotalHours);
```

Answer (score 13):

Para hallar la diferencia de tiempo entre dos objetos de la clase `DateTime` puedes restarlos ambos, el resultado arrojado de esta operación es un objeto de la clase `TimeSpan`, por esa razón no te permite asignárselo a un objeto de la clase `DateTime`. Por esa razón el compilador te arroja ese error.

Lo contenido en el objeto de la clase `TimeSpan` es el resultado de la resta de dos fechas, es decir, del tiempo entre ambas fechas:

```
TimeSpan tiempoDiferencia = DateTime.Now - fecharegistro;
```

Dependiendo de tus necesidades podrás realizar muchas operaciones entre objetos de las clases `TimeSpan` y `DateTime`. También puedes únicamente usar el objeto `TimeSpan` generado de la resta de las dos fechas para imprimir el tiempo de diferencia únicamente.

> ### Por ejemplo:
>
> **Adicionarle el tiempo de diferencia a la fecha de hoy:**
>
> ```
> DateTime resultado = DateTime.Today + tiempoDiferencia;
> ```
>
> **Adicionarle el tiempo de diferencia a la hora actual:**
>
> ```
> DateTime resultado = DateTime.Now + tiempoDiferencia;
> ```
>
> **Almacenar el tiempo de diferencia entre ambas fechas como texto:**
>
> ```
> string tiempo = tiempoDiferencia.ToString();
> ```
>
> **Imprimir el tiempo de diferencia entre ambas fechas:**
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine(tiempoDiferencia.TotalHours);
> ```
>
> Entre muchas otras cosas más.

Comment: no me deja sumar dos fechas y guardarlas en un `DateTime`

Comment: La acción de sumar dos objetos `DateTime` es distinta a su resta, normal que no lo puedas hacer igual que la resta. Lo que si usé en la respuesta y es válido, es sumar un objeto `DateTime` con uno `TimeSpan`. El primero denota fecha y el segundo un lapso de tiempo.

Comment: vale , ya he entendido