# Unity - Mejor forma de obtener el día y la hora

Tags: c#, datetime, unity

estoy haciendo un juego(mas específicamente para android) donde cada 20 minutos el jugador recupera una vida.

Lo que quiero hacer es poder obtener la hora cuando se cierra el juego y al volver a abrirlo obtener la hora actual y restarle la anterior para saber si ya pasaron los 20 minutos.

Cual seria la mejor forma de obtener la hora para poder restar y guardar ese valor?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo restar dos fechas en c#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162138/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-restar-dos-fechas-en-c)

Answer (score 0):

Aunque sea obvio, debes primero guardar la fecha y hora al cerrar el juego (en un archivo, db, PlayerPrefs... como veas). Luego al iniciar el juego obtienes la fecha actual y la restas.

Y para finalizar, esta pregunta responde a la tuya: [¿Cómo puedo restar dos fechas en c#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162138/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-restar-dos-fechas-en-c)